# R syntax highlighting in Jupyter Lab not working

Tags: syntax-highlighting, r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use a Macbook Pro running High Sierra.

At first I created a R virtual environment with:

```
conda create -n R r-essentials r-base
```

Then I installed Java JDK, inside the new environment with:

```
conda install -c cyclus java-jdk
```

I don't know why, but it kept prompting me to install JDK whenever I activated the R environment.

Then I installed Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab with:

```
conda install jupyter notebook
conda install jupyterlab
```

But when I run jupyter lab with R, it shows no syntax highlighting all text in blank. It works for Jupyter Notebook though.

What could be the source of this issue?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Kd9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue as you described, in order to resolve it I installed IRkernel library through an R session:

```
install.packages('IRkernel', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

After that I was able to run Jupyter lab, create a new notebook, and syntax highlighting was working for R. Hope this helps!